# Order a column in R based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I am wanting to order data in a tabyl in R by multiple criteria.

```
object <- c("a", "b", "c", "other", "N/A")
value <- c(7, 5, 9, 10, 3)
```

I would like the tabyl to be ordered from highest to lowest for objects "a", "b", "c", then "other", then "N/A".

Ideally it would be somewhat dynamic so that when I update the data it will automatically resort based on the above criteria.

Thanks!

I have tried arrange() but can't get it to work

Comment: Where's the table?

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base` solution.

```
df <- data.frame(object = c("a", "b", "c", "other", "N/A"),
                 value = c(7, 5, 9, 10, 3))

df$grp = ifelse(df$object == "N/A", 1,
                ifelse(df$object == "other", 2, 3))

df[order(df$grp, df$value, decreasing = TRUE), !names(df) %in% c("grp")]

  object value
3      c     9
1      a     7
2      b     5
4  other    10
5    N/A     3
```

And here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(object = c("a", "b", "c", "other", "N/A"),
                 value = c(7, 5, 9, 10, 3))

df |> mutate(grp = case_when(object == "N/A" ~ 1,
                             object == "other" ~ 2,
                             TRUE ~ 3)) |>
    group_by(grp) |>
    arrange(desc(grp), desc(value)) |>
    ungroup() |>
    select(-grp)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  object value
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 c          9
2 a          7
3 b          5
4 other     10
5 N/A        3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(grp = switch(object, other = 2, `N/A` = 3, 1)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  arrange(desc(value), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Comment: In this case, other and NA position will change based on value?

Comment: fair point, I missed that, changed my answer